# Finding the sum of $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$

Tags: probability

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}\newcommand{Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$Students’ scores on a test are normally distributed with mean $65$ and standard deviation $20$. However, the professor discovered that some questions were defective, so the professor decided to adjust the scores by subtracting each student’s score by $0.8$, then multiplying by $1.1$.

Find the sum of the first and second raw moments of the adjusted score.

---

My attempt

$$\E(1.1(X-.8))=1.1\E(X) = 65\cdot1.1 = E(Y)$$
$$\Var(X) = 20^2=400$$ $$\Var(1.1(X-.8))=1.21\Var(X)=1.21\cdot400=484=\Var(Y)$$
$$\Var(Y)=\E(Y^2)-(\E(Y))^2$$

So I have the following - $\E(Y^2)=484+(65\cdot1.1)^2=5596.25$

There the sum should be: $5596.25+(65\cdot1.1)=5667.75$.

My issue is that this is not one of the choices.

EDIT:

On my second attempt I did $E(Y) = (65-.8)\cdot1.1$ and got the right answer

Comment: Indeed, $E(a(X+b))=a(E(X)+b)$, not $a(X)$.

Comment: @Heavenly96 : And you could also write "eddit" instead of "edit" because you prefer it, and people would think it's a typo. Same sort of thing. If you're suggesting I down-voted your question, you would be mistaken. I rarely down-vote anything and I haven't voted either way on your question.